# paritioning table : impossible to enforce index uniqueness across partitions with a local index

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am actually trying to partition a table.

while I am altering this table

> ALTER TABLE  ttaa ADD constraint PK_ttaa  primary key clustered ( CODE, BRCODE, ttaa, IND, ttaa_NO, LINE_NO )
>   GO

I having this error .

> Cannot create unique index 'PK_ttaa' on table 'PK_ttaa' as a local index. The table partition condition and the specified index keys make it impossible to enforce index uniqueness across partitions with a local index.

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enforce uniqueness the partition keys must be a subset of the index keys, and must be in the same sequence.

Check the documentation for more detailed information: [Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.5 > Transact-SQL Users Guide > Partitioning Tables and Indexes > Indexes and partitions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/BABHCJGI.htm)

Comment: yes, thats correct I fixed that , now I am checking parallelism plan